# How to fetch Build ID of Job triggered from another job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have the following situation in a Jenkinsfile of Job A:

```
  ...
  ... // Some execution
  ...

  call Job B

  // When Job B runs successfully
  params.some_var_used_in_Job_C = BUILD ID of Job B
  call Job C
```

I have to know the BUILD ID of Job B after it succeeds and I need to pass it as a params to Job C. Can anyone suggest how I can do this?

Also is it possible that I can pass some variable from Job B to Job A (so that I can send that value to Job C later) ?

Comment: how are you calling the "Job B"? by using the parameterized remote trigger plugin or programmatically?

Comment: @KausUntwale programmatically using build().

Answer (score 2):

Should be as simple as this:

```
node {
    stage('Test') { // for display purposes
        def jb = build wait: true, job: 'JobB'
        println jb.fullDisplayName
        println jb.id
        //this will show everything available but needs admin privs to execute
        println jb.properties 
    }
}
```

If you want to pass a simple string from job B to Job A then in Job B you can set an env variable

```
env.someVar = "some value"
```

then back in job A

```
println jb.buildVariables.someVar
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kaus Untwale answer is correct. I've copied his answer into a declarative pipeline and added error handling.

From a upstream job:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {
        stage('Run job') {
            steps {
                // make build as unstable on error
                // remove this if not needed
                catchError(buildResult: 'UNSTABLE') {
                    script {
                        def jb = build wait: true, job: 'test2', propagate: false
                        println jb
                        println jb.fullDisplayName
                        println jb.id
                        
                        // throw an error if build failed
                        // this still allows you to get the job infos you need
                        if (jb.result == 'FAILURE') {
                            error('Downstream job failed')
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Get the build within a downstream job:

```
# job: test2

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Upstream') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // upstream build if available
                    def upstream = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(hudson.model.Cause$UpstreamCause)
                    echo upstream?.shortDescription

                    // the run of that cause holds more infos
                    def upstreamRun = upstream?.getUpstreamRun()
                    echo upstreamRun?.number.toString()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See the [api docs for the run class](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html). You'll also need to allow some calls from the downstream example as approved scripts or disable the Groovy Sandboxo on that job.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for downstream job, not upstream.